# SMS Gateway integration with Freeswitch

Tags: sms, freeswitch

I am looking for a highlevel overivew on how to integrate a hw SMS gateway with Freeswtich to create an SMS broadcasting solution. As per my research I need to have a hw SMS gateway that supports SMPP protocol, then freeswitch will use the mod_smpp to send the SMS towards it? Also, can we also recieve the SMS through this setup?

Looking for ideas for folks who might have worked on such a setup. Thank you!

I am looking for a high level design ideas for this solution. I tried to search online but could not get enough details.